# Rails form, get user id by username field

Tags: ruby-on-rails, forms

I've two models:

The first model:

```
class Url < ActiveRecord::Base
  attr_accessible :code, :target, :user_id, :user
  belongs_to :user, :dependent => :destroy
end
```

rails console

```
1.9.3p125 :001 > Url
 => Url(id: integer, user_id: integer, code: string, target: string, created_at: datetime, updated_at: datetime)
```

The second model:

```
class User < ActiveRecord::Base
  attr_accessible :description, :status, :username
  has_many :urls

  validates :username,
    :presence => true,
    :uniqueness => true

  def to_s
    username
  end
end
```

rails console

```
1.9.3p125 :002 > User
 => User(id: integer, username: string, status: integer, description: text, created_at: datetime, updated_at: datetime)
```

Now i have a form, for creating an url:

```
<%= form_for(@url) do |f| %>
  <% if @url.errors.any? %>
    <div id="error_explanation">
      <h2><%= @url.errors.count %> Error(s):</h2>

      <ul>
      <% @url.errors.full_messages.each do |msg| %>
        <li><%= msg %></li>
      <% end %>
      </ul>
    </div>
  <% end %>

   <div class="field">
    <%= f.label :user_id %><br />
    <%= f.text_field :user_id %>
  </div>

  <div class="field">
    <%= f.label :code %><br />
    <%= f.text_field :code %>
  </div>
  <div class="field">
    <%= f.label :target %><br />
    <%= f.text_field :target %>
  </div>
  <div class="actions">
    <%= f.submit %>
  </div>
<% end %>
```

To increase the user-friendliness I want to exchange the field user_id with the field username. What steps are necessary to do?

Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could use the [`collection_select`](http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActionView/Helpers/FormOptionsHelper.html#method-i-collection_select) helper to show a select box containing your users:

```
<%= f.collection_select(:user_id, User.all, :id, :username, :prompt => true) %>
```

This renders something like:

```
<select name="url[user_id]">
  <option value="">Please select</option>
  <option value="1">One User</option>
  <option value="2">Another User</option>
  <option value="3">...</option>
</select>
```

Comment: Thank you! This works well for me. But for thousands of users, there have to be a better solution, or?

Comment: I'd use some kind of autocompletion. Just google for [rails 3 autocomplete](http://www.google.com/search?q=rails+3+autocomplete).